# Selecting best k features using Chi-Square test

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, feature-selection, chi-squared

I have been trying to implement Chi-Square feature selection, wherein I select the best k features or the features that are highly dependent to the `Label`.

So far I am doing this:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

for col in all_cols:
    contingency_table = pd.crosstab(data[col] , y)
    stat, _, _ , _ = chi2_contingency(contingency_table.values)
```

Then I am selecting the top features as the ones having higher `stat` values.
Since sklearn already provides this feature using `SelectKBest(chi2,...)`.
So, is my implementation correct or in sync with the pre-built approach?